# Installation of php-mode on Windows?

Tags: indentation, microsoft-windows, php-mode

I want to install the [php-mode](https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode) on my windows 7 machine. I went through documentation of the cited website and there is no mention of what should be extra required to run this mode. Obviously, the PHP interpreter and some server, I would like to use MySQL as well. So what is the best setup to have them all (please cite the download websites where necessary). I know there are all-in-one installers for Windows like `XAMPP`, but what other workflows and alternatives are there other than that? What is recommended with regards to an effective Emacs ecosystem? I am just unaware of the possibilities.

What is special about installation of this mode in Windows apart from:

```
require ('php-mode)
```

in the dot emacs file?

I want also to indent an HTML content inside a PHP construct. I mean indentation of something similar to the MWE below:

**MWE -- page.php inside templates folder**

```
<?php
return "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$pageData->title</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    $pageData->content
  </body>
</html>";
?>
```

It might be helpful to share part of the dot emacs file code related only to `php-mode`. Thanks.

**Notes**

- I added the `c:\xampp\php\php.exe` to PATH variables but when I press `C-c C-r` of php code it throws this error: `php-send-region: Searching for program: no such file or directory, php`

**Update** 
There was a bug and thankfully fixed by the developer: https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/issues/228#issuecomment-77057035. Now, after applying the fix in the source and setting the PATH variable correctly in Windows to `c:\xampp\php` instead of `c:\xampp\php\php.exe`, `C-c C-r` is generating the `*PHP*` buffer.

**Question**
How to show the output of PHP code from the `*PHP*` buffer? What is the workflow to show the output in whatever browser available?

Comment: See the variable `php-executable` at line 110 of the current Github source code:  https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/blob/master/php-mode.el  The default is `/usr/bin/php`.  So, you may want to try:  `(setq php-executable "c:\xampp\php.exe")`  -- that being said, it's been about 15 years since I played with php / mysql / etc on Windows and I really don't remember how I eventually set that up, sorry.  In terms of indenting, I like to manually indent and have visual vertical lines help me with how things should line up, however, most people seem to prefer auto-indentation.

Comment: I M-x customize group -> php -> php-executable to `c:\xampp\php.exe` didn't solve it. Still throwing exactly the same error.

Comment: I see that line 1444 uses: `(call-process "php" nil php-buffer nil "-r" cleaned-php-code))))`.  Now that you have set the `php-executable` correctly, you can substitute `"php"` with the variable without quotation marks:  `(call-process php-executable nil php-buffer nil "-r" cleaned-php-code))))`  That should do the trick, but you'd need to modify the source, and if needed, re-byte-compile.  Alternatively, you can keep fiddling around with the path in an effort to help `call-process` find your `php` executable.

Comment: @lawlist, now a step forward, `C-c C-r` works by generating a the `*PHP*` buffer but how to show the output in the browser from there? Any help would be much appreciated if you still remember your workflow under Windows. Thanks.

Comment: Here are a couple of very basic examples using `start-process` on Windows XP -- I haven't ever used `php-mode`.  The following example contemplates the existence of a php file in the webserver directory named `test.php`:  `(start-process "process-name" nil "c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE" "http://localhost/test.php")`  The following example contemplates the existence of an html file anywhere on the computer that is readable:  `(start-process "process-name" nil "c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE" "y:/.0.lawlist.git/public_html/index.html")`